# WordSpec, using 'in' and pending doesn't seem to work

Tags: scala, scalatest

Moving from the Specs2 to Scalatest I tried using the WordSpec, but with no luck. I've used the sample from [Testing Actor Systems](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/scala/testing.html) and it didn't work for me for with the error. Then I've copied the basic test from the scaladoc and still have the same issue. Could you please guide me, what I'm doing wrong here:

```
class MasterSpec extends WordSpec {
  "A Set" when {
    "empty" should {
      "have size 0" in (pending)

      "produce NoSuchElementException when head is invoked" in {
        intercept[NoSuchElementException] {
          Set.empty.head
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This gives the following error message:

```
[error] /Users/bam/Projects/ppm/core/src/test/scala/net/batyuk/ppm/core/MasterSpec.scala:12: overloaded method value in with alternatives:
[error]   (testFun: () => Any)Unit <and>
[error]   (testFun: MasterSpec.this.FixtureParam => Any)Unit
[error]  cannot be applied to (org.scalatest.PendingNothing)
[error]       "have size 0" in (pending)
[error]                     ^
[error] one error found
```

Tried to move to FunSpec, but can't force myself into it, WordSpec seems to be much more natural for me

Comment: Works for me without error. I'm using scalatest 1.8 and scala 2.9.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a compiler error. I assume you have imported:

```
import org.scalatest.fixture.WordSpec
```

but you need to import:

```
import org.scalatest.WordSpec
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Idea has autoimported the fixture.WordSpec class. Feeling stupid.